# Thymeleaf: how to update existing database rows without creating new set of rows?

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

In my web application which I do using spring and thyme-leaf, I have a table in my database which I need to get updated by user. Find below the rows of my table.

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>From <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc"
                                aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
        <th>To <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </th>
        <th>th1(.min)</th>
        <th>th2</th>
        <th>th3</th>
        <th>th4 &#10095;</th>
        <th>th5</th>
        <th>th6</th>
        <th>th7</th>
        <th class="action">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr th:each="ir, rowStat : *{invRows}">
        <input type="hidden"
               th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].fromTime}"/>
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].toTime}"/>
        <td><p th:text="${#dates.format(ir.fromTime,  'HH:mm')}"/></td>
        <td><p th:text="${#dates.format(ir.toTime,  'HH:mm')}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"
                   th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].tvcDur}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"
                   th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].priceR[0].price}"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"
                   th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].priceR[1].price}"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"
                   th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].priceR[2].price}"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"
                   th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].lgPrice}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"
                   th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].crPrice}"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"
                   th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].crSpots}"/></td>
        <td class="actions"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The parameters are bind successfully with the mysql database. But the problem is instead of getting updated the existing values of the rows, the entire set of rows is added again and again each time I save the table. How can I update the table?

edit:
I have following drop down list. For each of the selection I want to have one table. ie I have to maintain 3 tables. How to do this?

```
<select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
        th:value = "${inventory.id}" id="channel" name="channel">
    <option th:value="Channel">Channel</option>
    <option th:value="ch1">ch1</option>
    <option th:value="ch2">ch2</option>
    <option th:value="ch3">ch3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should add as hidden field in your table the id of your element "ir". Something like this <input type="hidden" th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].id}"/>

Comment: what is "id" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table, you need to add the unique identifier of your object, then when the list goes to your controller the reposiroty will know is an update rather a creation.

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{invRows[__${rowStat.index}__].id}"/>
```

Comment: what should I use ad 'id'?

Comment: for each element of your list invRows, you should have an unique identifier inside right?